# PHP Curl setting headers origin

Tags: curl

I want to set header origin when connecting to some url that not owned by me

is it possible to set server [HTTP_ORIGIN] via CURL

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Origin: somevalue'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that will work.

Keep in mind - if setting custom HTTP headers, you must set them all at the same time.